# Responsive header not working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I was following a tutorial and they show the app being responsive, but I couldn't get it to be responsive and it look like I'm not the only one having the same problem. In the video they showed doing the responsiveness of the text without using media queries (I know how to do it with media queries). I tried to change the html **font-size to 10px and .8vw.** I'm using rem because according to this tutorial is't he best too use for responsiveness since it will grab the root value and do the conversion, in this case the root will be the html

https://jsfiddle.net/wearetamo/zckeynuq/

**Desktop view working**
[image]

**Mobile view not working**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<header class="header">
            <div class="logo-box">
                <img src="img/logo-white.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
            </div>

            <div class="text-box">
                <h1 class="header-primary">
                    <span class="heading-primary-main">
                        Outdoors
                    </span>
                    <span class="heading-primary-sub">
                        is where life happens
                    </span>

                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-white btn-animated">Discover our tours</a>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </header>
```

**CSS**

```
.
.
.
*, 
*::after,
*::before {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
     /* 80% of view port width which computes to
      font-size of 10.25px for my laptop screen */
}

body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    line-height: 1.7;
    color: #777777;
    padding: 3rem;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* HEADER */

.header {
    height: 95vh;
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(to right bottom,
                      rgba(126,213,111,.8),
                      rgba(40,80,131,.8) ),
        url('../img/hero.jpg'); 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top; 

    /*Giving shape to the picture*/
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 75%, 0 100%);
    /*To make  triangle 50% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%
    https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/
    */

    position: relative;
}

.header>.logo-box {
    position: absolute;
    top: 4rem;
    left: 4rem;
}

.header>.logo-box>.logo  {
    height: 3.5rem;
}

.header>.text-box {
    position: absolute;
    top:40%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
}

.header>.text-box>.header-primary {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header>.text-box>.header-primary>.heading-primary-main {
    display: block;
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 3.5rem;
    animation-name: moveInleft;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out
}

.header>.text-box>.header-primary>.heading-primary-sub {
    display: block;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1.74rem;
    animation: moveInRight 1s ease-out;
    backface-visibility: hidden
}
.
.
.
```

Comment: It's working for me. The font size is adjusted according to the width. https://jsfiddle.net/vg4y3kjL/

Comment: .8vw "works" but when you are in the desktop view makes everything look way bigger

Comment: @samuellawrentz as for right now my working solution is with media queries :(

`/*Media Queries*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    html {
        font-size: 30%;
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try doing this.

Set your `font-size` using [fluid-typography](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/)

```
font-size: calc([minimum size] + ([maximum size] - [minimum size]) * ((100vw - [minimum viewport width]) / ([maximum viewport width] - [minimum viewport width])));
```

and then set your `letter-spacing` using `vw` (viewport width).

Please see this link for [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zckeynuq/34/)

Sample code below.

```css
.header>.text-box>.header-primary>.heading-primary-main {
    display: block;
        font-size: calc(30px + (40 - 30) * ((100vw - 500px) / (1400 - 500)));
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 4vw;
        animation-name: moveInleft;
        animation-duration: 1s;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out
}

.header>.text-box>.header-primary>.heading-primary-sub {
    display: block;
        font-size: calc(13px + (18 - 13) * ((100vw - 500px) / (1400 - 500)));;
        font-weight: 400;
        letter-spacing: 1.3vw;
        animation: moveInRight 1s ease-out;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

---

If using [fluid-typography](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fluid-typography/) did not work on what you wanted.

I suggest you use variable font size using Media Queries.

Please see this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_responsive_text.asp).

Answer (score 1):

It is because for font size bigger than you window width

```
    <span class="heading-primary-main">
                            Outdoors
                        </span>
                        <span class="heading-primary-sub">
                            is where life happens
                        </span>
```

make those span font lower than your window width i.e make font-size:14px or 18px

```
@media (max-width:640px){
  .heading-primary-main{
    font-size:18px; 
  }
  .heading-primary-sub{
    font-size:14px;
  }
}
```